# Form data not posting to uri

Tags: php, html, forms

Can you tell me why when I click call my data is not posting to my action?

```
<body>
    <?php
        $login = '1236567';
        $password = '10152930';
        $officeNumber = array('0212177899','027899899','09111');
    ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form method="POST" action="https://live.domain.co.nz/call.php?login=<?php echo $login; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>&aparty=<?php echo $number; ?>phone&bparty=<?php echo $number;?>">
                    <?php
                        echo '<label for="officeNumbers">Office Number: </label>';  
                        echo '<select name="officeNumbers">';

                        foreach($officeNumber as $number)
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$number.'">'.$number.'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                <label for="callTo">Call: </label><input type="text" id="callTo">
                <input type="submit" value="Call">  
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have a question about why some client side code doesn't behave as you expect … then show us the client side code and not some PHP that generates it.

Comment: Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), you have some obvious machine detectable errors.

Comment: The `for` attribute on a label references the **id** of a form control. Some of your labels aren't associated with a control as they are trying to use the **name**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text input:

```
<input type="text" id="callTo">
```

… has no `name` attribute, so it cannot be a successful control (and thus submit any data).

Give it a `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks,  But that still does not tell me why my data is not posting in the action

Comment: @JessMcKenzie — The data encoded in the URI will be sent in the query string, not the body, so while it will be submitted as part of a post request, it won't be in `$_POST` but will be in `$_GET` (because `$_GET` is where PHP puts query string data).